# Ошибка памяти при выборке из бд NODE js

Tags: sql, база-данных, node.js

у меня возникает ошибка при выборке из бд(запрос написан на sql+node js + javascript).Я полагаю что приложению не хватает выделенной оперативной памяти чтобы сделать выборку. Как можно увеличить оперативную память в приложении? Либо можно ли записывать выборку прямиком в  файл без записывания в оперативку? Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, как вы её решили?Благодарю заранее за предоставленный ответ(скриншот ошибки предоставлю ниже)[image: Ошибка при выборке]

Также я читал что можно прописать в package настройки чтобы увеличить память , но видимо мозгов у меня не хватило как это сделать так что если кто то поможет с этим я буду благодарен( скидываю скрин package.json) [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: допустим вы увеличили размер памяти доступной ноде (легко гуглится как это сделать) или с помощью pg-query-stream перенаправили вывод результатов на диск, а что будете дальше будете делать с данными?

Comment: их просто надо будет добавить в файл и все , но с этим уже разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось запрос был слишком большим для памяти ноде.Чтобы увеличить память я использовал в терминале node --max-old-space-size=12000 dist/main и все заработало